# Compute complex limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan(z)}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I want to know how to compute complex limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan(z)}{z}$, that is, when $z\in \mathbb{C}$. I have tried writing $h=h_1+ih_2$ and then computing
$$\lim_{h_1+ih_2\rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan(h_1+ih_2)}{h_1+ih_2}$$ and therefore I can express the tangent of the sum of tangents. However  this doesn't help much either because I end up with a rather long expression and then I don't know if I have to make $h_1\rightarrow 0$ first and then $h_2\rightarrow 0$ or do it simultaneously.

**P.S.** I know that the limit should be $1$, but I am interested in the process

Comment: Write your fraction as $\frac{\sin z}{z}\frac{1}{\cos z}$ and consider the limit of the two fractions separately.

Comment: What's your definition of tangens of complex argument? Is it $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$? Then probably $\sin,\cos$ of complex argument are defined by their taylor series, right? With this definition it shouldn"t be that hard to prove $\frac{\sin(z)}{z} \to 1$ as $z \to 0$ ( and obviously $\cos(z) \to 1$ as $z \to 0$), from which you can conclude.

Comment: `tan(z)=z+O(z^3)` , so `tan(z)/z=1+O(z^2)`

Comment: How would you compute the limit for real arguments? – Note that $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\tan(z)}{z}$ is the *derivative* of the tangent at $z=0$, that works also in the complex domain.

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on what tools are already available to you at this point in your course, and on the definitions of the complex trigonometric functions that you are using. Assuming that you are defining $\tan z = \frac{\sin z}{\cos z}$ and $\sin z = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} z^{2n+1}$ you can argue that for any $z\ne 0$ in a small neighbourhood of $0$, you have that
$$
\frac{\tan z}{z} = \frac{1}{\cos z}\cdot\frac{\sin z}{z} = \frac{1}{\cos z}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!} -\frac{z^4}{5!} \cdots \right)
$$

Taking limits (there is some justification needed regarding the convergence of the series) you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
L = \lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \ {\tan z \over z}
$$

Note that we can express $L$ as
$$
L = {L_1 \over L_2}
$$
where
$$
L_1 = \lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \ {\sin z \over z} = 1
$$
and
$$
L_2 = \lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \ \cos z = 1
$$

Hence,
$$
L = {L_1 \over L_2} = {1 \over 1} = 1
$$

Comment: How do you justify $L_1=1$ and $L_2=1$?

Comment: Since the question was how to extend the limit to complex numbers, you need to show how the limits you've cited can be extended to complex numbers.